# mysterious sum of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let

$$S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots$$

$$S_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \cdots$$

So

\begin{align}
S_1 - S_2 = {} & 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots \\
& {} - \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} - \cdots \right] \\
= {} & 0 + 1 + 0 + \frac{1}{2} + 0 + \frac{1}{3} + 0 + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots \\
= {} & S_1
\end{align}

That makes $S_2$ zero, right?

The reason I am asking is because I was under the impression that $S_2 = \ln 2$.

What did I miss?

Is it that $S_1$ is divergent and $S_2$ is convergent and it's not allowed?

Comment: When $S_1$ is divergent, the cancellation is not allowed.  The question whether "$1 + \infty = \infty$ implies $1 = 0$" is not much different from the question "does $1*0 = 2*0$ implies $1 = 2$". If an operation destroy information (e.g. adding a $\infty$ or multiply by a $0$), then cancellation won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't rearrange the terms of a sequence that doesn't converge absolutely without changing it's value, and you can't group series like that. For example:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i = 1 -1 + 1 - 1 +\cdots \ne (1-1) + (1-1) + \cdots 
$$

which would make it look like the sum converges to zero, but the above sum clearly diverges.

Comment: But it's apparently OK to make it $\frac{1}{2}$ :)

Comment: @stevemarvell That's for the physicists to say lol.

Answer (score 4):

You're saying $\infty - S_2 = \infty$; therefore $S_2=0$.

That is not valid.  If $f$ approaches $\infty$ then the limits of $f$ and $f-5$ are both the same, but that doesn't mean $5=0$.

Answer (score 3):

> *That makes $S_2$ zero, right ?*

Not if $|S_1|=\infty.~$ ;-$)~$ Basically, infinity is for addition what $0$ is for multiplication. So, for instance, just like $S_1\cdot S_2=S_1$ does **not** imply $S_2=1$ when $S_1=0,~($since one can't exactly divide by $0),$ so also $S_1+S_2=S_1$ does **not** imply $S_2=0$ when $S_1\to\infty.~$ A simple method of evaluating $S_2$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1200014/1).